# Splitting a line in perl by whitespace, but ignoring whitespace in quotes

Tags: regex, perl, split

I've got a line like this:

```
A2     IDENT    =     'THING1','THING2'
A3 IDENT   =   'G'
A4   IDENT   =         'SOME THING','ANOTHER THING'
```

And I'm trying to get tokens like this:

```
A2,IDENT,=,'THING1','THING2'
A3,IDENT,=,'G'
A4,IDENT,=,'SOME THING','ANOTHER THING'
```

I can do a split on `\s+` and then on `,` (to split the last section), but the spaces in the last section mess it up.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @words = parse_line( qr{\s+}, 1, $_ );
    dd(@words);
}

__DATA__
A2     IDENT    =     'THING1','THING2'
A3 IDENT   =   'G'
A4   IDENT   =         'SOME THING','ANOTHER THING'
```

Outputs:

```
("A2", "IDENT", "=", "'THING1','THING2'")
("A3", "IDENT", "=", "'G'")
("A4", "IDENT", "=", "'SOME THING','ANOTHER THING'")
```

Note: Using [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) enables you to more easily see what your resultant array contains.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
for my $line (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = $line =~ /('.*?'|\S+),?/g;
    print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}
__DATA__
A2     IDENT    =     'THING1','THING2'
A3 IDENT   =   'G'
A4   IDENT   =         'SOME THING','ANOTHER THING'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:\s+|,)(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

You can split by this and remove `empty splits` later.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/10